# how do we know the L = 4n^2 in euclidean TSP algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, traveling-salesman, euclidean-algorithm

I am trying to understand the euclidean TSP algorithm.
From most of the explanations available online, we set the value of L = 4n^2.

is there any explanation for why L has that value?

[image: resources]

Here is the link to the source
http://viswa.engin.umich.edu/wp-content/uploads/sites/169/2019/03/9.pdf

Comment: This is a question for the CS Stack Exchange, but to answer it quickly here, we want to snap all of the points to integers for later in the algorithm, and not have it perturb the (relative) objective too much. 4n^2 is "enough" (cf. Lemma 2.1) but you could take L larger (at the expense of running time) or smaller (to something on the order of n/epsilon, I think, at the expense of potentially having to track its contribution to the approximation ratio more carefully).